# How to select first 10 elements from database using SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

There is a query like `SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id`. I want to select only first 10 elements. How can I do this?

P.S. I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Should be noted that the ORDER BY defaults to ASC, where DESC is also an option, but must be explicitly stated - `ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM clients ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's all you can do with a SELECT (taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

So the statement you are looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that OFFSET is very helpful to paginate:

LIMIT 10 OFFSET 11

for the second page of 10.

Comment: But it isn't a good idea, see this: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: @Benjaco is correct with respect to pulling many pages as the DB must start from 0 each time. The offset tool is best suited for UI use cases where it's unlikely the user will go beyond the first page very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL way is to use:

```
   SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
```

which is MySQL-specific. For a longtime there was no counterpart in other databases but the SQL:2008 standard introduces an additional syntax:

```
   SELECT * FROM clients FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

and:

```
   SELECT * FROM clients OFFSET 1 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

But the problem is, that this syntax isn't supported by MySQL and most other databases, yet. In case you care about portability you should follow the development there.

Please mind that you should always `ORDER BY` clauses else the result might be random on different calls.